# Breadcrumbs are not showing in angular 7 while page reload

Tags: angular

I have implemented breadcrumb in my angular 7 application using below code
breadcrumbs.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute, PRIMARY_OUTLET } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'blm-bread-crumbs',
  templateUrl: './bread-crumbs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bread-crumbs.component.scss']
})
export class BreadCrumbsComponent implements OnInit {
  breadcrumbs: any = [];
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    debugger
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .pipe(map(() => this.activatedRoute))
      .pipe(map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) { route = route.firstChild; }
        return route;
      }))
      .pipe(filter(route => route.outlet === PRIMARY_OUTLET))
      .subscribe(route => {
        // debugger
        let snapshot = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
        this.breadcrumbs = [];
        let url = snapshot.url;
        let routeData = route.snapshot.data;
        console.log(routeData);
        routeData.breadcrumb.forEach((item: any) => {
          // console.log(item);
          this.breadcrumbs.push({
            url: item.url,
            label: item.label,
            terminalOnly: item.terminalOnly
          });
        });
      });
  }

  renderRoute(data: any) {
    if (data.url) {
      this.router.navigate([data.url]);
    }
  }

}
```

below is my breadcrumbs.component.html

```
<div class="breadcrum">
  <span *ngFor="let data of breadcrumbs">
    <a (click)="renderRoute(data)">
      {{data.label}}</a><span *ngIf="!data.terminalOnly">>></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

My issue is breadcrumbs are not loading / disappearing after page reload/ refresh. 
and when i logged in first time also breadcrumbs are not showing

Please help me to resolve issue thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have the same feature on my application, but [mine works correctly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pwjs6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Here is the code if it might help :

```js
export class RouteBreadcrumbsComponent {

  breadcrumbs = [];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    let buffer = [];

    /* 
       Listen for router events in reverse order (to get all events).
       From the snapshots, return its path and its breadcrumb.
    */
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd),
      map((event: ActivationEnd) => [
        event.snapshot.data && event.snapshot.data.crumb || undefined,
        this.determineCorrectPath(event.snapshot),
      ]),
      filter(([crumb, url]) => !!crumb),
    ).subscribe(([crumb, url]) => buffer.push({ crumb, url }));

    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(event => {
      this.breadcrumbs = buffer.reverse();
      buffer = [];
    });
  }

  determineCorrectPath(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const path = snapshot.routeConfig.path;
    const params = snapshot.params;

    // Path = route with a param, so get the param
    if (path.startsWith(':'))
      return params[path.replace(':', '')];
    // Path = '' = route group or root route of a lazy loaded module, so take the parent path
    else if (!path)
      return snapshot.parent.routeConfig.path;
    // Path can be used as is
    else
      return path;
  }

  buildRoutingArray(crumbIndex: number) {
    return this.breadcrumbs
      .slice(0, crumbIndex + 1)
      .map(crumb => crumb.url)
      .join('/');
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wish to get help on your own code, please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue, so that we can play with it.

Comment: I am getting   ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of null

Comment: @Santhosh you just have to modify my code to use your model (my code only contains a string to display as the breadcrumb, the path is then calculated automatically)

Comment: yes i did but i am not able to get it, could you please post your working code through the stackblitz

Comment: @Santhosh sure, [here it is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pwjs6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks @Maryannah , will try and let you know the status

Comment: @Santhosh so what's the status ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try moving your event handling from the onInit to the constructor, the routing event can be missed in the lifecycle hook.